# apt get install one package from sid

Tags: debian, apt

How is it possible to install one package from the `sid`?

I have installed `buster` but want to install one package which is not yet available in the `buster` repository

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=tesseract-ocr

I want to install tesseract 4.1.

Before I install 4.1 i want to check if any other packages needs any updates which is not yet available in `buster`. How to check for that?

I **only** want to update tesseract

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. First read [Dont Break Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian).
2. Second, ask yourself "Do I really **need** the shiny new version, or do I just **want** it?", and "Do I know what actual benefit I'll get from the new version, or is it just a case of 'newer is better'?.

   If you don't actually need it, don't upgrade.  If you can't name any actual benefits that are worth hassle of making a FrankenDebian, then don't upgrade.
3. Your best option is to wait until tesseract 4.1 arrives in [buster backports](https://backports.debian.org/news/buster-backports/). The downside to this option is that there is no guarantee that this will ever happen.
4. Your second best option is to download the debianised source packages for tesseract and build them yourself in your buster system.  i.e. backport it yourself.
5. If you don't want to build it yourself but you're still impatient, you could add sources.list entries for `sid` to your system, and configure apt so that it uses `buster` (or better yet, `stable`) by default.  e.g. by adding the following to `/etc/apt/apt.conf` (or to a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`)

   ```
   APT::Default-Release "stable";
   ```

   And then over-ride the default to install tesseract-ocr with:

   ```
   apt-get -d -u -t sid install tesseract-ocr
   ```

   You may (and probably will) have to list other tesseract-related packages on the same command line.  This will be an iterative process of running it again and again, adding more package name(s) to the command line each time until it offers to actually install the packages without complaint.

   Remove the `-d` (aka `--download-only`) option when you are sure you want to install the packages.

   Note that there is no guarantee that this will upgrade **only** tesseract.  It will upgrade tesseract and every dependency of tesseract that requires a newer version than your buster system has, and every versioned dependency of all of those packages.

   If one of those versioned dependencies happens to be `libc6` or some other very commonly used package, that will trigger a cascade of further upgrades.  At which point, you'd best either cancel the upgrade or just upgrade everything to `sid`.

Comment: too much effort